# Why do I get different output running xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xmlspy

I am doing a very simple xslt for a source node like:

```
  <p>
        <media type="photo" id="lr002662" rights="licensed">
            <title>Logging in Canada</title>
        </media>Logging is cutting down trees for <definition>
            <word-term>lumber</word-term>
            <word-definition>wood</word-definition>
        </definition>. Loggers are also called <i>lumberjacks.</i>
    </p>
```

I am running this source node on my xslt stylesheet, once in xmlspy, I got the following output:

```
 <para>
        <media type="photo" source="lr002662" rights="licensed">
            <resource.title>Logging in Canada</resource.title>
        </media>Logging is cutting down trees for <italic>lumber</italic> (wood). Loggers are also called <italic>lumberjacks.</italic>
    </para>
```

But then I run this in command line with saxon9he.jar file using the same xslt stylesheet, I got the following:

```
      <para>
        <media type="photo" source="lr002662" rights="licensed">
            <resource.title>Logging in Canada</resource.title>
        </media>Logging is cutting down trees for 
            <italic>lumber</italic>
             (wood)
        . Loggers are also called <italic>lumberjacks.</italic>
    </para>
```

As you can see, the text after the media tag now contains so many carriage returns in it, and that is not what I want. I've been using the XMLSpy so never noticed this problem. Could any experts suggest a way to debug or provide my xslt?

Answer (score 3):

The differences are due to [the manner in which the Altova XML processor handles whitespace in mixed content.](http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?x20_generalinformation.htm)

> **Whitespace in XML document**
>
> By default, the Altova XSLT 2.0 Engine strips all boundary whitespace
>   from boundary-whitespace-only nodes in the source XML document. The
>   removal of this whitespace affects the values that the `fn:position()`,
>   `fn:last()`, `fn:count()`, and `fn:deep-equal()` functions return. For more
>   details, see [Whitespace-only Nodes in XML Document](http://manual.altova.com/AltovaXML/altovaxmlcommunity/index.html?x20_generalinformation.htm) in the XPath 2.0
>   and XQuery 1.0 Functions section.

AltovaXML strips the "boundary-whitespace" text nodes between elements that have whitespace-only content:

> A boundary-whitespace-only text node is a child whitespace-only text
>   node that occurs between two elements within an element of mixed
>   content.

As lwburk suggested in his answer, **you can instruct other processors to do the same by adding the following to your stylesheet:**

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

However, you cannot get AltovaXML to preserve the spaces [because they have not implemented  `xsl:preserve-space` or `xsl:strip-space`](http://manual.altova.com/xmlspy/spystandard/index.html?xslt1engineimplementation.htm) and will always strip them out.

Answer (score 1):

The line breaks are there in the source, so I'd expect them to appear in the transformation's output, unless they were specifically removed. You can strip all white-space-only text nodes using:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

This should be at the top level of your stylesheet (as a child of the root `xsl:stylesheet` element).

Comment: More precisely, not "other spaces", but any white-space-only text node.

Comment: @thank you, do you have any idea why it is shown correctly in XMLSpy?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Indeed. Updated.